# Insert into TABLE($TABLE_VARIABLE) snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using snowflake
I am looking to insert data to a table while using a variable
The purpose of using the variable is so when I can change it without doing a find and replace all

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE DB1.PUBLIC.HUMANS (
  HUMAN VARCHAR(32)
)
;
```

The following works

```
INSERT INTO DB1.PUBLIC.HUMANS
SELECT 'SUCESS';
```

The following does not work

```
SET EXPORT_TABLE = 'DB1.PUBLIC.HUMANS';

INSERT INTO TABLE($EXPORT_TABLE)
SELECT 'FAILURE';
```

HOWEVER this works.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE($EXPORT_TABLE);
```

Is there is a way to insert into a table defined by a table literal?

**reference documentation:**

> https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/literals-table.html
> https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert.html

======================================================
**Update:** Answer found by comments below.
Thanks to Biraja Mohanty and Greg Pavlik

To make this work have to wrap the IDENTIFIER().

```
INSERT INTO IDENTIFIER($EXPORT_TABLE);
```

> https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables.html

Comment: To add to what Biraja Mohanty shared, the reason table() worked for select but not for insert is because TABLE() is a function that returns a table. If you pass as its only parameter the name of a table, the TABLE function will return the rows in that table.

Comment: Ah that is a good bit of in sight. thanks @Greg Pavilk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SET EXPORT_TABLE = 'DB1.PUBLIC.HUMANS';

INSERT INTO identifier($EXPORT_TABLE)
SELECT 'FAILURE';

Comment: Thank you @Biraja Mohanty That did the trick! So simple yet so hard to find documentation